# How to convert a pandas dataframe into a list of multiple NamedTuple

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I am working on a code where I need to map multiple `NamedTuple` placed into a list.
Below is the code example - My main problem is around the mapping of the `List` of dual `NamedTuple` `PeopleName` and `PeopleAge` - I'm not clear how can this be done. Should this be done into two steps, 1/ extract the full row into a generic `NamedTupe`, then 2/ split the record into different `NamedTuple` `PeopleName` and `PeopleAge`

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List

import pandas as pd

data = [["tom", 10, "ab 11"], ["nick", 15, "ab 22"], ["juli", 14, "ab 11"]]
people = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Age", "PostalCode"])

PeopleName = NamedTuple("PeopleName", [("Name", str)])
PeopleAge = NamedTuple("PeopleAge", [("Age", int)])
PeoplePC = NamedTuple("PeoplePC", [("PostalCode", str)])

# The code below is not correct
Demography = NamedTuple(
    "Demography", [("names", List[(PeopleName, PeopleAge)]), ("postalcodes", PeoplePC)],
)


def to_nested_tuple(k, g):
    peoples = list(
        g["Name"].to_frame().itertuples(name="Person", index=False),
        # rec["Age"].to_frame().itertuples(name="PeopleAge", index=False),
    )
    return Demography(peoples, PeoplePC(k))


d = [to_nested_tuple(*item) for item in people.groupby("PostalCode")]

print(d)
```

Comment: Can you please share some example output, I’m not entirely sure I understand what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This annotation `List[(PeopleName, PeopleAge)]` throws `TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.List; actual 2, expected 1`.

That tuple with 2 different types should also be annotated with `typing.Tuple`:

```
List[Tuple[PeopleName, PeopleAge]]
```

But, to annotate arguments it is preferred to use an abstract collection type such as `Sequence` or `Iterable`:

```
Demography = NamedTuple(
    "Demography", [("names", Sequence[Tuple[PeopleName, PeopleAge]]), ("postalcodes", PeoplePC)],
)
```

Instead of applying `to_nested_tuple` for each group I would go straightforwardly in the following way:

```
d = [Demography([(PeopleName(row['Name']), PeopleAge(row['Age'])) for _, row in group.iterrows()], PeoplePC(k))
     for k, group in people.groupby("PostalCode")]
```

Now, the result would be printed as:

```
[Demography(names=[(PeopleName(Name='tom'), PeopleAge(Age=10)), (PeopleName(Name='juli'), PeopleAge(Age=14))], postalcodes=PeoplePC(PostalCode='ab 11')),
 Demography(names=[(PeopleName(Name='nick'), PeopleAge(Age=15))], postalcodes=PeoplePC(PostalCode='ab 22'))]
```

Comment: Thanks, however, the final result doesn't look correct, should it not be a list of tupe of `PeopleName` and `PeopleAge` with `PeoplePC` for each common postal code ?

Comment: Also, how do you transfer this annotated Sequence into the output from the pandas df?

Comment: @Michael, what do you mean with "transfer this annotated Sequence into the output" ? I've posted the result of your final statement `print(d)`

Comment: Thanks @RomanParekhrest - in my initial code - how do you transfer the raw dataframe into the sequence : ```def to_nested_tuple(k, g):
    peoples = list(g["Name"].to_frame().itertuples(name="Person", index=False),)
    return Demography(peoples, PeoplePC(k))```

Comment: Thanks, @RomanPerekhrest - this works as expected - thanks for taking the time to update your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use `list(df.itertuples())` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do but for each dataframe records inside the list I should have a dual mapping to `PeopleAge` and `PeopleName` - at the end I should have a list of (`peopleAge` and `peopleName`) with one correcponding `PeoplePC` if that makes sense